# Self Signed Certificate for localhost error in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic11g

I am trying to setup SSL on my weblogic server to test my application when it runs on https.
I followed the steps outlined [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/weblogic-configure-ssl-for-a-managed-server)

except that instead of a Custom Identity and Custom Trust, I used Custom Identity and Java Standard Trust.

However when my setup is already finished, I am unable to view my webpage in both FireFox and Chrome when I hit below url

```
https://localhost:8000/MyApp
```

Only Internet Explorer shows my webpage.

In firefox 38 I am hitting

Secure Connection Failed

> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8000. Cannot
>   communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
>   (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

In Chrome 45

SSL server probably obsolete.

> ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION

Only IE 11 shows my page, only if I disable the Check for server certificate recognition.

I am not sure why.  I generated my Self Signed Certificate with JDK 1.6 and I am using the same machine to view my webpage but I cannot see my page rendered.

I was thinking that in Firefox, there should be something like
[image]

But unfortunately there is none.

Any weblogic experts around?

Comment: What JDK version are you running WebLogic on?

Comment: I also used JDK 1.6  for my weblogic

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to upgrade your Java security policy to Unlimited Strength. Download the files below and replace them in your JDK installation. This resolved a TLS issue that I was having the other day with WebLogic not using the latest encryption algorithms.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Comment: I already downloaded those files and replaced my JDK files but the issue still occurs.  Is there something that needs to be checked next.  Thanks for your time by the way, appreciate it very much

Comment: Have you tried the -Dweblogic.security.SSL.nojce startup parameter as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13707/ssl.htm#SECMG388